# AWS EC2 to RDS SQL Server maximum connection count

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2014, amazon-rds

I have the EC2 t3.medium and RDS SQL Server 2014 with db.m4.large..

I create one application with 1000 threads, all thread connect to the database to just select the single row from the table with the primary key where.

When I run my application from the the t3.medium EC2, and check the CloudWatch for RDS, it say maximum 500 concurrent connection is made to the database at a time.

Also When I run the 2 instances of my application on same EC2, around 700 maximum concurrent connection is made to the database at a time...

But when I run the application in two EC2 t3.medium at same time to the same rds, around 1100 max concurrent connection is made to the database at a time..

My questions are:

1. How many max connection is supported by RDS SQL Server 2014 with db.m4.large?
2. Is there are any setting in the EC2 or RDS to increase maximum number of concurrent transaction at time from single EC2 ? (As single EC2 gives 700 db connection, but two EC2 gives the 1100 db connection)

Comment: number of connections determined by the instance class

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/862387/aws-rds-connection-limits m4.large is 648 connections

Comment: @ArunK I think it that count was for the RDS MySQL server... and after that AWS changed it's Counting expression... I think So..

Comment: @ArunK At least it the RDS Parameter group I can not found the max_connections property..

Comment: ah ok you are talking about SQL server